# Only allowed certain string in a column to be send to MySQL

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question. Am I able to allow only certain strings to be place into a DataFrame and then uploaded to MySQL?

For example, I want to only allow 'A' and 'B' onto MySQL with the column name of 'Channel'. I have an idea of doing it as followed:

```
if 'A' and 'B' not in df['Channel']:
    pass
```

But it seems that there is still some strings which are not related would be send onto it. So is there any way to do this?

Comment: First decide where you want to limit the value - in python or in MySQL?

Comment: I would like to do this in Python, before the value are being sent to MySQL.

Comment: If so then the question is not related to MySQL. I'd recommend to remove the tag which is obviously unrelated.